# Cannot open file in python-Jupyter

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, jupyter

I just install Anaconda on my system. and the location where Anaconda installed is C:\Users\Administrator\Anaconda3 I am trying to open a test file that I created and kept in the same location by jupyter but its not working and giving me error that file not found.
I ran pwd command from jupyter and its giving me output as '/home/jovyan/binder'

Can someone please help me what is going wrong in accessing file

Comment: Which subcommand are you running in Jupyter (notebook, qtconsole, etc.) And how are you starting Jupyter - in commandline or another way? If you're starting from commandline in a particular directory (say the command is `jupyter notebook`), then Jupyter should start a shell in that directory.

Comment: I am using Jupyter notebook with the link of jupyter with the below link:https://hub.mybinder.org/user/ipython-ipython-in-depth-mokx7ow9/notebooks/binder/Index.ipynb

Comment: Is there any other way to work on jupyter...I am accessing in this way only

Comment: I see. I have not used binder and it seems like a good tool. Yes, you can run jupyter notebook on your local system too, from the jupyter python package. You need to add the above information (that you're using binder) in the question because otherwise people won't be able to help you.

Comment: One more question - from my understanding, binder is used for accessing notebooks in your github repo. Therefore it seems like you'll only be able to access files within your repo, starting from the top level directory. Can you tell me the path of the file you're trying to access?